# Finding all keys that correspond to same value in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

I have an unordered_map looking like this:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> theMap2 = {{1,"a"}, {2,"b"}, {3,"c"}, {4,"a"}};
```

I want to find all the keys that have same value lets say "a". Any suggestions beside the obvious way:

```cpp
std::vector<int> arrKeys;
std::string value = "a";
for (const auto& element : theMap)
   if (element.second == value)
        arrKeys.push_back(element.first);
```

Comment: Where did the answer with copy_if go?
All you had to do was change the lambda to capture value by & and change the auto parameter to const auto&

Comment: @KABoissonneault No, you also need to adapt the output iterator, since `copy_if` will try to copy the key-value *pair*.

Comment: @dyp Can it be easily adapted? If so, can you post an answer?

Comment: @KABoissonneault Writing an adapter is harder than writing a `transform_if` algorithm; both should best be done via an existing library (boost facilitates writing new iterators, for example). But then, you can probably find a library that directly solves the OP's problem.

Comment: Your own solution is best from many points of view.

Answer (score 9):

I think the "obvious" way is excellent: it is simple, short and easy to read.

Another option is to use stl algorithms. What you need is `transform_if` algorithm so you can say:

```
std::transform_if(std::begin(theMap), std::end(theMap),  std::back_inserter(arrKeys), check_value, get_value);
```

but there is no such in stl. What I can suggest is:

```
std::vector<int> arrKeys;
std::string value = "a";

auto check_value = [&](std::pair<const int, std::string> const& p)->bool
{
    return (p.second == value);
};

auto end = std::end(theMap);
auto it = find_if(std::begin(theMap), end, check_value);
while (it != end)
{
    arrKeys.push_back(it->first);
    it = find_if(std::next(it), end, check_value);
}
```

Comment: I thought you suggest copy_if to create new map only with desired values, followed by transform to fill arrKeys. what is your idea?

Comment: Sorry, I was distracted by the predicate and didn't pay attention to the issue of transforming the key-value pair to the value. While `copy_if` can still be used via iterator adapters, a `transform_if` is probably more reasonable.

Comment: @dyp Wouldn't you need to write something like `back_first_inserter` for `copy_if?

Comment: @Barry Yes, some kind of adapter is required, either for the map iterators or the output iterators. range v3 contains `view::values`, but I haven't worked with that library so I'm having a hard time coming up with a decent (idiomatic) solution.

Comment: @dyp @Barry I tried to write a `back_first_inserter` down below, would appreciate any feedback on it.

Comment: The value type of [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is `std::pair<const Key, T>` but without the const qualifier it will construct a temporary `std::pair<Key, T>` to pass into your function taking a `const &` which may not be what you want or expected.

Answer (score 3):

More out of interest than anything else, I wrote a basic wrapper which could be used for `copy_if`. It is like `std::back_inserter`, but instead of just inserting the object it is given, it inserts `std::get<N>(obj)`. This makes it usable for `std::array`, `std::tuple` and `std::pair`.

To insert the `pair.first`, as we want in this example, we use `back_n_inserter<0>`.

```
template< std::size_t N, class Container >
class back_n_insert_iterator : public std::iterator< std::output_iterator_tag,
                                                         void, void, void, void >
{
public:
    back_n_insert_iterator (Container& c) : c{c} {};

    //could protect this by checking that the get call is_convertible to the value_type
    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) operator= (T&& collec) 
    {
        c.push_back(std::get<N>(std::forward<T>(collec)));
        return *this;
    }

    decltype(auto) operator* () { return *this; }
    decltype(auto) operator++ () { return *this; }
    decltype(auto) operator++ (int) { return *this; }
private:
    Container& c;
};

template< std::size_t N, class Container >
back_n_insert_iterator<N,Container> back_n_inserter( Container& c )
{
    return {c};
}
```

Now we can use our adapter in a `copy_if` call:

```
std::copy_if(theMap.begin(), theMap.end(), 
             back_n_inserter<0>(arrKeys),
             [&value](const auto& el){return el.second == value;});
```

Thanks to @dyp for all suggestions.

Comment: You could enhance the `back_first_inserter` to a `back_n_inserter` if you drop the restriction of the function parameter via pattern matching; `template<typename T> void operator=(T&& t) { c.push_back(std::get<N>(std::forward<T>(t))); }` (possibly SFINAE-protected). I'm still not convinced that this is a better idea than to write a `transform_if`, btw. With Niebler's range v3, it should be possible to write something like `std::vector<int> arrKeys = theMap | view::remove_if([&](auto const& p){ return p.second != value; }) | view::keys;` (not tested)